# SSI $DOCUMENT_URI regular expression

Tags: html, regex, dynamic, cgi, ssi

I have a nav.shtml file in which I am setting a class on the current menu item as follows:

```
Faculty'>http://root/level1/level2/page.shtml">Faculty & Staff
```

This is fine for the top-level pages, but a few have subpages and I would like to be able to set the class on the top-level menu item if the current page is a subpage as well.  E.g. There is a "Faculty/Staff" menu item which goes to an overview page, faculty.shtml, then there are some links on that page to individual faculty/staff pages in a subdirectory.  If I'm looking at one of the individual subpages, I still want the class to get set on the "Faculty/Staff" menu item.

So, I need something like:

```
"if $DOCUMENT_URI=/level1/level2/page.shtml *or* if $DOCUMENT_URI=/level1/level2/level3/*.shtml".
```

I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax...  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you, based on the example provided:

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_URI = /\/level1\/level2\/page\.shtml/ || $DOCUMENT_URI = /\/level1\/level2\/level3\/.*.shtml/" -->
```